# JWT is always returning unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, postman

I have implemented the [JWT Application](https://www.techgeeknext.com/spring/spring-boot-security-token-authentication-jwt-mysql)

I am using JWT 0.9.1 version

I am able to generate the Json web token, but when I pass to the `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/greeting` method I am always getting the same error like 401 Unauthorized.

**SpringSecurityConfig.java**

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/authenticate", "/api/v1/register","/api/v1/basicauth")
                /*.permitAll().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")*/
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                        exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

**GreetingController.java**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: yes,I logged in then I got JWT, with that token I am calling the greeting method

Comment: Can you show me content of SpringSecurityConfig

Comment: I think that you need to show all jwt files content @@!

Comment: https://www.techgeeknext.com/spring/spring-boot-security-token-authentication-jwt-mysql this is the same example I have implemented

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208232/discussion-between-ravi-kumar-ravanam-and-do-thanh-dat).